# List of python to make plot

Tags: python, list

I have two list:

The first list, has two str names
The second list, has two dataframes

I want to make two charts. For each chart, I want it label.

when I executed this code, I have this error

> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

Can You help me?

```
etiquet=['EUR','USD']
divisasIndica=[df1,df1]


def ch1(div, pares):
    for j in zip(div,pares):
        dtm=pares[j]
        etiqueta=div[j]             

        fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Candlestick(x=dfm['Date'],
                            open=dfm['Open'],
                            high=dfm['High'],
                            low=dfm['Low'],
                            close=dfm['Price'])])


        fig.update_layout(
            title= etiqueta,
            yaxis_title='Px',
        )

        fig.show()



ch1(etiquet, divisasIndica)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`j` is not an index, it is a tuple of the elements in the lists, change

```
dtm=pares[j]
etiqueta=div[j]
```

to

```
 dtm=j[1]
 etiqueta=j[0]
```

`j[0]` is holding the values from the `div` list and `j[1]` is holding the values from the `pares` list.

Comment: j[1]? but my list has 100 … What do I put between[] … I cant to put 1, 2, 3 o 99 o 100... I will have to put i, j or another thing, not?

Comment: no, on every iteration `j` will have the different values of the lists

Comment: maybe is the typo `dfm` instead of `dtm`

Comment: This I have seen... And This It isn't

Comment: I don't get the charts. What can it is?

Comment: I don't know, you should create another question with a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Now its ok. I have start the computer and the output is ok. With your solution I have the best code for my graphics. Thx